# convert list of element to int and not the string in python

Tags: python, list

I wish to convert this list to int and not the element of string inside it.

just to convert those are integer.

a = ["a\n", "222\n", "bbb\n", "7777"]

is there a way to do so?

I tried

```
for x in a:
   x = int(a)
```

but this convert all.

Comment: im a bit confused what is the expected output you are after?

Comment: pretty sure that won’t convert them all but throw an error

Comment: result = [re.sub('[^0-9]','',b) for b in a if re.sub('[^0-9]','',b).isdigit()]
this will yield the result of ['222', '7777']. is that what you are after

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is your expectation. But I think you are having the string in your list so you are getting the string. Try the below and check if this helps.

```
#this is all string
#a = ["a\n", "222\n", "bbb\n", "7777"]

#try with the below set
a = [10,11,'1','a','b',12,13,'14','c']

intPart = [x for x in a if isinstance(x, int)]
stringPart = [x for x in a if isinstance(x, str)]

print(intPart)
print(stringPart)

#output
#10, 11, 12, 13]                                                                                                                                               
#['1', 'a', 'b', '14', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt a conversion, and return the value unchanged if it's not possible:

```
def to_int(x):
    try:
        return int(x)
    except ValueError:
        return x

a = ["a\n", "222\n", "bbb\n", "7777"]
new_a = [to_int(x) for x in a]
print(new_a)
```

Output:

```
['a\n', 222, 'bbb\n', 7777]
```

Answer (score -1):

*Edited: I did not quite understood what OP mean by "convert this list to int"*

I suppose you want:

```
a = ["a\n", "222\n", "bbb\n", "7777"]

[ int(el) if el.isnumeric() else el     
   for el in a 
]
```